# Can finder move to next item with same starting letter like windows explorer will?

Tags: macos, finder, keybindings

On windows inside a folder if there are multiple files with same starting character, if I press the character again it selects another file. How to do this on mac?

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way (or close to it)

Yoh have to press and hold a starting character and it will jump to next and so on.

Granted the holding time is bit tricky to master.